# UICollectionViewFlowLayout: Cells with different widths, but same interitem spacing

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a UICollectionView with a UICollectionViewFlowLayout and cells that have different widths. I want my cells to float left and have the same spacing between them. I don't care if there is extra white spacing on the right of every row. Any ideas? Thanks!

Thank you very much!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement custom UICollectionViewFlowLayout, and override this method:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect
```

Similar question has been already asked here: [Left Align Cells in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview)