# Left align in UlCollectionView

Tags: ios8, uicollectionview

How is to make the items of the UlCollectionView to stand in the left within the line

[image]

Such position (upper screenshot) can take place only in the case when there is the only item on the line; if there is more than one element on the line (items are smaller or the screen is wider),the elements are left justified within the line and position looks like desired:

[image]

The settings of UICollectionViewFlowLayout are the following:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flowLayout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 20.;
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 5.;
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(23., 15., 23., 15.);
flowLayout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionVertical;

self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout = flowLayout;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Left Align Cells in UICollectionView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview)