# How to remove space between cells in UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

How to remove space between two cells in `UiCollectionView`? Min spacing is not working.

[image]

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (collectionView.tag==101)
    {
        return CGSizeMake((_collView.frame.size.width),(_collView.frame.size.height));

    }
    else
    {
       return CGSizeMake((_collView2.frame.size.width/3)-20,300);
    }
}
```

But this is not working.

Answer (score 21):

*[image]
*

Set Min Spacing for cells and for Lines to Zero
and replace your code by

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:       (UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:   (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (collectionView.tag==101)
{
    return CGSizeMake((_collView.frame.size.width),(_collView.frame.size.height));
}
else
{
   return CGSizeMake((_collView2.frame.size.width/3),300);
}
 }
```

Answer (score 16):

Use UICollectionViewFlowLayout for those purposes:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *flow = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
flow.itemSize = CGSizeMake(cellWidth, cellHeight);
flow.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;
flow.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
flow.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because of how UICollectionviewFlowLayout works. You could provide a custom collectionview layout: 
[Left Align Cells in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview)

Or use a 3d party solution:
https://github.com/mokagio/UICollectionViewLeftAlignedLayout

Answer (score 0):

use this code, based on your design adjust the width and height.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

CGSize s = CGSizeMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2-10,
[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2.9-7);
return s;
 }
```

bellow code adjust the edges of collection view

```
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section {
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(2, 6,2, 6);
}
```

Use both delegates and change the width and height

Answer (score -2):

A method called `minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex` from `UICollectionViewFlowLayoutDelegate` could help you. The minimunIteritemSpace set the space beetween items horizontally, for example try this code:

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionView *)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section  
{ 
  return 0; // This is the minimum inter item spacing, can be more
}
```

Also you can use the `edgeInsets` to change the space beetween items.

Comment: This will join columns, rows will still be separated.

Answer (score -2):

```
- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{


return 10.0;
}

- (CGFloat)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{


return 10.0;
}
- (UIEdgeInsets)collectionView:
(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout insetForSectionAtIndex:(NSInteger)section
{


// return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,8,0,8);  // top, left, bottom, right
return UIEdgeInsetsMake(20,20,20,20);  // top, left, bottom, right
}
```