# Reverse Align of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    var x = CGSize(width: 88, height: 88)

    if currentCollectionviewMode == .photos {
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            x = CGSize(width: 88, height: 88)
        } else {
            x = CGSize(width: CGFloat(originalImages[indexPath.row - 1].size.width) / CGFloat(originalImages[indexPath.row - 1].size.height) * 88, height: 88)
        }
    } else {
        x = CGSize(width: 88, height: 88)
    }
    return x
}
```

before running this code everything is well, but when this code run my collectionView align change from rtl to ltr my semantic is forceRightToLeft, any suggestion?

I tried `CGATransform(scaleX:-1,y:1)` but `collectionviewcells` stick to left and with scrollToitem in `viewDidAppear()` collectionview show cells bad.

Comment: What actually your requirement is?

Comment: @dahiya_boy i want my collectionview cell rtl but when i run sizeforitem method cells stack to left

Comment: @Mr.Zee did you solve your problem?

Comment: @MilanNosáľ with CGATransform(scaleX:-1,y:1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To define a different alignment of cells in `collectionView`, you will have to either implement your own `UICollectionViewLayout` ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016798/2912282) for reference), or use some library for that (e.g., [AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout](https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout)).

Answer (score 0):

In every subview of the collectionView cell do this

[image]