# Swift - Change UICollectionViewCell size programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am struggling to change the size my items in the CollectionView.

**Custom Flowlayout class** found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49717759/6257435):

This is my CollectionView:

```
class ExampleViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource {

let theCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v.backgroundColor = .white
    v.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    v.layer.cornerRadius = 30
    return v
}()

let columnLayout = FlowLayout(
    itemSize: CGSize(width: 50, height: 50),
    minimumInteritemSpacing: 10,
    minimumLineSpacing: 10,
    sectionInset: UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 20, bottom: 10, right: 20)
)
```

I tried changing the **itemSize**  but that doesnt do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't assigned you `flowLayout` to the `collectionView` either try:

`theCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = columnLayout` or

First define your layout :

`let columnLayout = FlowLayout( ...`

Then define your collectionView like this:

`let theCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
 let v = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout:columnLayout)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is Code for CollectionViewCell Size Change

(Note:- Change values according to your Requirement!)

```
 let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/4, height: screenWidth/4)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
        cell2.collectionView2.collectionViewLayout = layout
```