# align single UICollectionViewCell to the left of the collectionView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I've got a collectionView that is inside a tableView cell. The collectionView has multiple sections. If a section has only one cell, the cell appears centered. How can I align that single cell to the left?

[image: collectionView inside tableView cell]

The collectionView has the following `flowLayout`:

```
let flowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
flowLayout.scrollDirection = .vertical
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
flowLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
flowLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(flowLayout, animated: true)
```

Comment: Have you looked into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview

Comment: Well all answers from that link move all collectionViewCells to the left, so all cells from all sections. I only want that behavior for that section that only has one cell.

Comment: You can add one more ghost cell when you have only one cell in a section and hide it, then the first cell will be left-aligned.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Since `sectionInset` is the same as `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets { }` protocol, one could call this protocol to know which section has only one cell left.

You can replace :

```
flowLayout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

With:

```
  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

    if collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section) == 1 {

         let flowLayout = collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout

        return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: collectionView.frame.width - flowLayout.itemSize.width)

    }

    return UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

}
```

This red cell is the only one left in the second section , and it is left aligned:

[image]

Comment: Don't forget to use *UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout* for this method.

Answer (score 9):

I had same issue.
My solution is to change of collectionView's estimate size.

Automatic -> None

[image]