# How Can I align the colectionViewCells to the left?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uikit, alignment

I have a c`UIolectionView` that sometimes has only 1 item. If that is the case, the item is aligned in the middle, see picture:

[image]

But what I want, is that the item is aligned to the left.

I have found this answer on StackOverflow, [leftAlign cells in UIColectioniew - StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview), but when I added the class given in the accepted answer to my codeBase, and added this to the `viewControler`:

```
        let leftAlignLayout = AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout(horizontalAlignment: .left, verticalAlignment: .top)
        gamesColectionView.collectionViewLayout = leftAlignLayout
```

it did align the way I wanted, but it made the cells very small(see picture)

[image]

I also tried to add this from Github: [AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout - GitHub](https://github.com/mischa-hildebrand/AlignedCollectionViewFlowLayout) but that had the same result.

I tried fixing that bug by adding this to my `viewController` File:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
           layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
           sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 130, height: 130)
    }
```

but that didn't work.

does anybody have a suggestion on how I can fix this? I don't know what I did wrong or what I forgot to do.

thanks a lot!
BSM

Comment: Where is your data array ? Are you using custom cell? Please share the your cell's picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manage your cell with below code. Do not forget to add `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
// your code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 8.0
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 8.0
    let width = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 40.0) / 4
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 98.0)
    return layout
}()
```

And:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.collectionView?.collectionViewLayout = layout
    self.collectionView!.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom:0, right: 0)
}
```

You don't need to use sizeForItemAt. If you want more you can look [my project](https://github.com/kasimoz/Weather_iOS/blob/master/WeatheriOS/ViewControllers/ForecastViewController.swift). Check constraints of your imageView with it's superview

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to do anything special to get the `collectionViewCells` left aligned.

If the `constraints` are proper, the `cells` will automatically start rendering from the left.

```
class VC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
            return cell
        }

        func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
            return CGSize(width: 130, height: 130)
        }
    }
```

Simply set the `scrollDirection` to `vertical` or `horizontal` as per your requirement within the `storyboard` itself.

There is no need to use any 3rd party library to get that working.

[image]