# iOS - implementing custom collection view layout

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I have a working default collection view flow layout but I am trying to have my cells left aligned (not the default center stretch). I got some good answers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview). It says I need to use a custom layout. But how do you even implement a custom layout? I created a file and it is ready to go but how do I hook it up to the VC with the Collection View?

Here is what is in my Collection View's VC:
created an outlet for the layout at top

```
@IBOutlet weak var tagsLayout: TagsLayout!
```

My current implementation of default flow layout at bottom:

```
extension ItemViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        let text = allTags[indexPath.row]
        let font: UIFont = UIFont(name: "Baskerville", size: 15) ??  UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0) // set here font name and font size
        let width = text.SizeOf(font).width
        return CGSize(width: width + 20.0 , height: 30.0) // ADD width + space between text (for ex : 20.0)
        }
//
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt: Int) -> CGFloat {

        return 4.0
    }

}
```

I've seen this may be necessary in viewdidload but .delegate is not recognized / not in my custom layout

```
        if let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? TagsLayout
        {
            layout.delegate = self
        }
```

TagsLayout:

```
import UIKit

class TagsLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    
    required override init() {super.init(); common()}
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {super.init(coder: aDecoder); common()}
    
    private func common() {
        estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
        minimumLineSpacing = 10
        minimumInteritemSpacing = 10
    }
    
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(
                    in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        
        guard let att = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in:rect) else {return []}
        var x: CGFloat = sectionInset.left
        var y: CGFloat = -1.0
        
        for a in att {
            if a.representedElementCategory != .cell { continue }
            
            if a.frame.origin.y >= y { x = sectionInset.left }
            a.frame.origin.x = x
            x += a.frame.width + minimumInteritemSpacing
            y = a.frame.maxY
        }
        return att
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply set the `delegate` of `collectionView` to `self` in the `viewDidLoad` method of `ItemViewController`.

```
class ItemViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tagsLayout: TagsLayout!
    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = tagsLayout
        collectionView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Then you can verify by simply:

```
extension ItemViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        print("Now it getting called... :)")
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Just updated my post right before you sent that to say I have that but .delegate is not recognized / not part of my custom layout. How does that delegate method look in the custom layout class? Thanks

Comment: What is `TagsLayout` inheriting from? Add the `TagsLayout` code to your question.

Comment: ```UICollectionViewFlowLayout``` added.

Comment: Okay, so where are you assigning this layout to the `collectionView`? I've just updated the code above. You'll have to set the `delegate` of `collectionView` to `self`. I've added the code to set the layout to the `collectionView` above.

Comment: That's my question lol. Not sure how to do that. I set the custom layout in IB and hooked it up to the outlet I posted.