# How to make Collectionview cells near to each other in swift?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, cell

**I need cells one nearby another like below**

[image]

**but i am getting like this**: in short phones they are very far from one another

[image]

for collectionview i have given constraints:

```
height = 80, leading = trailing = 0, top = 20
```

and in viewdidload:

```
  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //services collectionview cell
    let serviceLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    serviceLayout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
    serviceLayout.minimumLineSpacing = 0
    serviceLayout.estimatedItemSize = UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize
    self.servicesCollectionView.collectionViewLayout = serviceLayout
    servicesCollectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .always
    servicesCollectionView.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "contentSize", options: .new, context: nil)
   }
```

i haven't given anything more then this.. please do help.. to get collectionview cells to come near to each other

Comment: https://dev.to/kevinmaarek/using-collectionview-compositional-layouts-in-swift-5-1nan

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Align Cells in UICollectionView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22539979/left-align-cells-in-uicollectionview)

Comment: I have gisted a CollectionViewLayout for that : https://gist.github.com/celian-m/211d1f3b442134265be6772ffcbd50e7