# Left aligning UICollectionView Cells without using Custom Layout

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewflowlayout

I'm trying to create a left aligned collection view. The most poplar way of achieving this seems to be by using Custom Collection view layouts (ex: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36016798/11515703). However, I'm trying to do this without using Custom Layout, because it removes the collection view section headers I've got setup. Is this possible?

I tried doing this like this:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        let inset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 20, bottom: 0, right: view.frame.width)
        
        return inset
    }
```

The above code achieves the result but it leads to a lot of issues as it conflicts with the collection view flow layout rules. Is there an alternative method ?

This is the result I'm trying to achieve:
[image]

Note: I'm using collection view cells with variable width.

Answer (score 0):

`contentInset`, the custom distance that the content view is inset from the safe area or scroll view edges, [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset)

```
collectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(
    top: 0,
    left: 16,
    bottom: 0,
    right: 16)
```

| Without `contentInset` | With `contentInset` |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Comment: I'm using a collection view with variable cell width, so this doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `contentInset`

By default, UIKit automatically adjusts the content inset to account for overlapping bars. You use this property to extend that distance even further, perhaps to accommodate your own custom content.

[Read in apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619406-contentinset)

Comment: Tried this and it doesn't work as ```contentInset``` would be the same for all the cells and I'm using cells with variable width.