# How to override the default position of UICollectionViewCells?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a vertical `UICollectionView` which contains 5 different types of cells. The 4 of them take the whole width of the `UICollectionView`, so the `func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize` gets the work done.

The other 2 are of the same size but their default position needs to be changed; I want them to be aligned from left to right, instead of the centered default.

Here's how I set up my UICollectionView:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    switch typesOfCellsArray[indexPath.row] {
    case .createVoiceRoom:
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 70)
    case .voiceRooms:
        let height: CGFloat = content.voiceRooms.count > 3 ? 256 : 128
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: height)
    case .seeMoreVoiceRooms:
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.width, height: 50)
    case .newStatus:
        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width + 40)
    case .status:
        let width = collectionView.frame.width / 4
        return CGSize(width: width, height: width + 40)
    }
}
```

Here's how they look:

[image] [image]

And here's what I want:

[image] [image]

I think I need to subclass `UICollectionViewLayout` to achieve that, but I've failed... Here's what I did:

```
class HomeCollectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {
    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }
        let layoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect)
    
        layoutAttributes?.forEach({ attributes in
            if collectionView.cellForItem(at: attributes.indexPath) is NewHomeStatusCollectionViewCell {
                let column = attributes.indexPath.row % 3
                attributes.frame.origin.x = CGFloat(column-1) * attributes.frame.width
            }
        })
    
        return layoutAttributes
    }
}
```

Of course, I have set this class as the UICollectionView layout. Any ideas?

Comment: I got it done by using Mischa's amazing module https://stackoverflow.com/a/44329212/4388495

Answer (score 0):

You can insert each of you cell into separate **section** and then control following:

```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets { }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat { }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize { }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed; I placed the bottom cells in a second section and they are still in the center.