# Swift 3: Centering UICollectionView Cell right on the middle of screen

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

Been a few weeks on design practice and an idea came up on my mind, i was trying to center my **`UICollectionView`** in the middle of the screen, i have used the  **`Horizontal`** for this purpose, i tried to do that on storyboard, by editing the top,right,left,buttom pixels but it only works on the **iPhone 7 Plus Simulator** 
[image: ScreenShot 2017]

it is all fine,  after switching to the normal iPhone 6 it goes to the left a bit while i got it centered on the property inspector

[image: Screenshot]

**i am gonna be totally honest with you** i haven't tried any codes to perform that action only in storyboard,

if you got something helpful, share it, i would appreciate it

**for reference** this is my property inspector.....
*thanks for visiting*
[image: Screen]

Comment: What you mean is you want the `UICollectionViewCell` to be centered, correct? From the AutoLayout blue lines it looks like the collection view itself is properly positioned, just the cell is off because of the fixed spacing at the beginning. I would take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37065909/7264964

Comment: Yes mate, already figured the layout issues, the main problem is the cell

Comment: all the solutions were outdated mate

Comment: it looks like the view inside the cell is not properly aligned. Did you check your layout consteaints for the box with rounded corners?

Comment: yes, that is an imageView, i removed the imageview to see if its the problem, but no

Comment: or maybe remove the insets and work with the layout constraints for the views inside the cell

Comment: there is a fix left inset of 45, this could be the problem

Comment: i tried, it did not work. it is not a problem with insets, otherwise i'll have to center it in code