# How to center horizontally self-sizing UICollectionView Cells?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout

I have a collectionView and the direction is set to Horizontal and every cell just contain a UIlabel and it's using autolayout to determine the width of the cell.

for example, there are three cells and it's default behaviour.

`|[x] [xxx] [xxxxxxxxx]                       |`

but the requirement is to center align these three cells if the total width of all cells doesn't exceed the width of the screen.

**the left inset for the first cell should be**

`leftInset = (screen width - (first cell width + second cell width + third cell width + total spaces between the three cells) /) 2`

the result would be

`|            [x] [xxx] [xxxxxxxxx]           |`

I have found a great answer for the cells with fixed width from [How to center horizontally UICollectionView Cells?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34267662/how-to-center-horizontally-uicollectionview-cells), but doesn't work on self-size one.

would be much appreciated if you would help.

Comment: I think you will need to look into creating your own UICollectionViewLayout that will position the cells as you require.  This tutorial shows the basics of how to do it [link](https://www.raywenderlich.com/164608/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest-2)

Comment: I am stuck with the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

Really annoying, that Apple doesn't provide ready-to-use layouts for such things...

In the end I came up with following flow layout:

```
class HorizontallyCenteredCollectionViewFlowLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        guard let attributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
        guard let collectionView = self.collectionView,
            let rightmostEdge = attributes.map({ $0.frame.maxX }).max() else { return attributes }

        let contentWidth = rightmostEdge + self.sectionInset.right
        let margin = (collectionView.bounds.width - contentWidth) / 2

        if margin > 0 {
            let newAttributes: [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? = attributes
                .compactMap {
                    let newAttribute = $0.copy() as? UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
                    newAttribute?.frame.origin.x += margin
                    return newAttribute
            }

            return newAttributes
        }

        return attributes
    }
}
```

This basically consists of the following steps:

1. calculate the `contentWidth`
2. calculate the (left+right) `margin` between the `contentWidth` and the `collectionView`s width
3. apply the margin if necessary*, which leads to a entering of the content

* Negative margin means the content is bigger than the `collectionView` and the attributes should therefore stay unchanged => scrollable and left aligned as one would expect.

Comment: This works pretty well for me, but it seems to assume that `last.frame.maxX` is the rightmost edge, which isn't always true. I think it would be more robust to use `attributes.map { $0.frame.maxX }.max()`?

Comment: @Tom Thx for this notion, just updated my answer accordingly.