# How to horizontally center collectionView items with dynamic width?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout, uicollectionviewflowlayout

Hello I've looked around and haven't been able to find a solution to my question yet.  I'm trying horizontally center items of a collectionView where items will have all have different widths and sizes.  Because of this, some rows in the section may have 2 items, some may only have 1.  Most solutions I've seen around set the UIEdgeInsets but since I don't know whether the row contains how many items, in addition to not knowing the item size, I've been having a hard time getting this to work.

[image: Sample Image]

I've attached a picture to show you what I current have. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Comment: FYI, I ended up using the [KTCenterLayout](https://github.com/keighl/KTCenterFlowLayout)

Comment: a duplicate, find the answer from [https://stackoverflow.com/a/68734263/10505343]

Comment: Did you get it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Choosing correct UI Widget, to achieve what you want in minimum effort. According to your screenshot `UITableView` should be the right choice for achieving this.

Here are some tips

1. Use custom `UITableViewCell` with a label horizontally and vertically centered within the `UITableViewCell`
2. Use dynamic sizing, so that if the text grows then the cell grows too.
3. Remove the separator and background color of the cell, cell's contentView.

Happy coding

Comment: A TableView doesn't achieve what I want, since it would show only 1 label per "row" and I want to to show as many labels in a row as allowed by the label width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the open source project [TagCellLayout](https://github.com/riteshhgupta/TagCellLayout) written by **riteshhgupta** in `GitHub`.

Sample Code to initialize the layout:

```
import TagCellLayout

let tagCellLayout = TagCellLayout(alignment: .center, delegate: self)
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = tagCellLayout
```

[image]

I know you might write the lots of code for this, but it would be helpful greatly and even you can customize to different layout alignments.

Comment: Thanks I'll check it out