# UICollectionView oval shaped custom cell

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview

How to generate oval shaped cells in `UICollectionView` using custom cell. Below is the image that I am trying to achieve.

[image]

Have no idea about this how to achieve this, gone through several links but doesn't got.
Please guide. 
Thanks

Update: What i tried is

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {


    return CGSize(width: collectionView.frame.size.width/3.0 - 8, height: collectionView.frame.size.width/2.5[![enter image description here][2]][2] )
}
```

For this design but it's not working as required, it becomes
[image]

Comment: so what is your problem exactly, just the size of the items ?

Answer (score 16):

TL;DR: (Example can be found here: https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO39160339)

---

Phew, you will hit 3 problems with this view:

1. Self sizing `UICollectionView` cells that take a text as a cell lenght
2. Align collectionView cells to center not left-right
3. Rounded corners in subview

So let's start:

**1)**

This is a little bit tricky and not that much straightforward. The first thing you should do it let auto-layout do the trick for you. So design cell and collectionView in your storyboard and xib file and then in your controller class to this:

```
if let flowLayout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSizeMake(1, 1)
}
```

The right way to do is for example `viewDidLoad` func. Of course if you'll override an layout later remeber about this `if`.

Then for a label you want to self size you'll need to set:

```
cell.titleLabel.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = 50
```

The value you use in that two examples doesn't matter that much. If you set estimatedItemSize low, you basically asking for self sizing.

**2)**

For doing this you'll need to override the layout class. I highly recommend use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/38254368/1317394 from @Alex Koshy answer.

**3)**

That part is easy.Just add subview on the bottom on custom cell and set cell view background color to transparent. And add corner radius in cell like this:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.roundedView.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height/2

}
```

Here is an output effect:
[image]

And here is the link to repository with this example:

https://github.com/JakubMazur/SO39160339

Enjoy!

Comment: It helped me a lot thanks but yet some issues not exactly what required, working on them.

Comment: Can you tell how to chnage the color of roundedView on selecting cell, i tried but doesn't work for me in didselectmethod

Comment: Just override `setSelected:` method in cell

Comment: didn't got you and another issue is the spacing between cells setting it to 10 but not want to show three cells in a row.On 6 and 6+three rows are showing but much spacing than 10 and on 5 only two cells in a row.

Comment: func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
    
        let marginStaticValue : CGFloat = 10
        return UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, marginStaticValue, 0, marginStaticValue)
    }

Comment: Ok you need to figure out what you try to accomplish. They cannot auto fit to text and has always 3 cells in a row.  What will happen if you put 3 very long words in the same line? Should they shrink with dot in the middle? Or leave two words in the line and move third to next line? Note that words will have different length

Comment: that's ok i am talking about he space in between cells that is not reducing as i fixed it to 10.

Comment: can i set fixed space between cells irrespective of cell width. What's happening with me is cell width height fixed but space between cells is increasable but not decreasable

Comment: Yes, that's flowLayout fault. Implement second point from above list and this will do the trick. Flow layout align things to left and right. You need center alignment and then insets from storyboards will apply to center.

Answer (score 1):

add imageview / button (your choice) to your collection view cell with frame as big as the whole cell, make the cell background clear add the color you want to the button and set layer.cornerradius of your button to exactly how oval u want (e.x 1/2 of button height is exact circle).

Answer (score 1):

if u are trying to make a cell in UIcollectionview, corners round

then u can try this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell:CellCollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("MyCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)as! CellCollectionViewCell
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.blueColor()
    cell.layer.cornerRadius=26 //try with different values untill u get the rounded corners
    cell.layer.masksToBounds=true
    cell.cellLabel.text=label[indexPath.row]



    return cell
}
```

Comment: 26 is ok for proper oval shape, but not getting 3 cells in a row

Comment: - (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
In this method return collectionview.width/3...it will give you 3 cells in one row.
Do this only if the label text size is fixed, what if the text size increases much more.

Comment: if u want three cells in a row go to our main.storyboard select collectionView in the viewController after selecting collectionView,go to size Inspector in the properties pane in size inspector set min cell spacing for calls and lines. adjust the value according to your requirement hope this might solve ur problem

Answer (score -1):

Get a cell object

add subview(container view) on contentView

Set border radius of container(e.g. 2)

Add other UI elements inside container.