# How to center align CollectionView Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, alignment

Hi have a collectionview.
Each cell's width is screenwidth/3. Means 3 cells in a row.
Now. If have 10 or 11 cells then there will be 4 rows. and there are 1 or 2 cells in last row.
The problem is ,I want to align these cell to center without changing its size . now cells are left align.

Note: I want to achieve this with in a section(Because collection-view already have multiple sections).
Image attached what i want to achieve .[image]

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/30104749/7734643

Comment: i have already try this. But result is not same as i want

Comment: You can try to increase cell width this is not what you want but it can give you a batter look  in case you have 1 or 2 cells in a row.

Comment: According to design, i cant increase the width.Width shoud be same but cell will be centered align

Comment: @TaimoorSuleman do u got any solution?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this using multiple sections. Number of section should be

```
numberOfSection = totalItemCount/3 > Int(totalItemCount/3) ? Int(totalItemCount/3) + 1 : Int(totalItemCount/3)
```

dont use ceiling. Then number of items in section should be

```
numberOfItemInSection = totalItemCount-section*3 < 3 ? totalItemCount-section*3 : 3
```

Then implement the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate. Where in `collectionView(_ collectionView:, layout:, insetForSectionAt:)` set,

```
let minimumInterItemSpacing: CGFloat = 8.0
// minimumInterItemSpacing should be same in the delegate function
let itemCountInSection = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: section)
let edgeSpace = (collectionView.bounds.width - ((itemCountInSection*self.itemWidth) + (minimumInterItemSpacing*(itemCountInSection-1)))) / 2
return UIEdgeInsets(top: self.topSpace, left: edgeSpace, bottom: self.bottomSpace, right: edgeSpace)
```

set other delegate methods as it suits you.

Comment: Here in Collectionview we already have multiple sections.This Image attached is one section.SO i cant do this.