# How to properly set section inset on a UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass with dynamically sized cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

My goal is to have dynamically sized cells in a `UICollectionView`. In addition, when the scrollable `contentWidth` of the `UICollectionView` is less than the `bounds` of the Collection, I want the items centred within the collection.

[image: Goal]

**Approach thus far:**

I am trying to do this in the cleanest way possible. I have self-sizing `UICollectionViewCells` where Auto-Layout can determine the size of the cell from the contraints of the content. For this, my cells override the `preferredLayoutAttributesFitting` function, returning the appropriate width for their content.

My custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` subclass uses this width information, provided by the `UICollectionViewCell` to properly size up the cells.

The only methods overridden on my custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` are:

- `layoutAttributesForItem(at...)`
- `layoutAttributesForElementsIn(rect...)`
- `shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange...)`

The dynamic sizing of the `UICollectionViewCells` works flawlessly.

**The problem:**

Using this approach, I have no prior knowledge of the size of each cell (each can be different). I'd like to implement the `UICollectionView`'s `delegate` method to provide an inset to center my content within the collection view. For this, I'm thinking I should implement and override

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets
```

The problem lies in the fact that the inset method is called early in the layout process, where I have no knowledge of the `contentSize` that will be determined during layout.

Here's a stack of the various layout methods, for a single complete layout pass, in the order that they run:

```
prepare started
prepare finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect started
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect started
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect started
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect finished
prepare started
insetForSectionAt 0 called <--- The datasource has knowledge of the presence of cells but the cells themselves are not yet dequeued
prepare finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 0] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 0] finished
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 1] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 1] finished
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 2] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 2] finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 0] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 0] finished
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 1] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 1] finished
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 2] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 2] finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect finished
prepare started
prepare finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect started
<--- At this point Cells DO return valid sizes through Autolayout
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 0] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 0] finished
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 1] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 1] finished
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 2] started
layoutAttributesForItemAt [0, 2] finished
layoutAttributesForElementsInRect finished
```

For a single layout pass, multiple calls are made to the various layout methods but only at the very end is the size information from Auto-layout available from the different cells to pass on to the layout.

I noticed that the `sectionInset` delegate function is getting called early, before the cells have been properly dequeued and allowed to run their Autolayout constraints. Therefore, it is impossible to inform the inset with a correct value at the time it is called.

Using such an approach, is it possible to force a call to recalculate the `sectionInsetAt` after the layout pass or should I change the technique completely?

**Things I have tried:**

I tried querying the `collectionViewLayout`'s `collectionViewContentSize` from within the `insetForSectionAt` delegate function. Unfortunately, this cannot be used during a layout pass as the layout is currently in progress. It causes a crash with error:

```
[CollectionView] An attempt to update layout information was detected while already in the process of computing the layout (i.e. reentrant call). This will result in unexpected behaviour or a crash. This may happen if a layout pass is triggered while calling out to a delegate. UICollectionViewFlowLayout instance is (<App.ViewportToolbarFlowLayout: 0x7f8a5261add0>)
```

I tried using the `collectionView`'s `contentSize` method to get at the size during the execution of the `insetForSectionAt` delegate method, but it does not provide correct data at the moment it runs within the layout process.

Answer (score 0):

Posting the answer here. I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38254368/6929003) by Alex Koshy which helped me a lot.

Basically, the work has to be performed in the `layoutAttributesForElementsIn(rect...)` since it is the only place where the full layout picture is ever available. I've adapted Alex's code to handle both horizontal and vertical `UICollectionViews` (which may not be what everyone wants but is what I needed). I use the `scrollDirection` property of the layout to determine whether elements will be centred horizontally (when `scrollDirection` is `.horizontal`) or vertically (when `scrollDirection` is `.vertical`).

Here is the code:

```
override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
    guard let collectionView = collectionView else { return nil }

    guard let superLayoutAttributes = super.layoutAttributesForElements(in: rect) else { return nil }
    let computedAttributes = superLayoutAttributes.compactMap { layoutAttribute -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? in
        return layoutAttribute.representedElementCategory == .cell ? layoutAttributesForItem(at: layoutAttribute.indexPath) : layoutAttribute
    }
    guard let attributes = NSArray(array: computedAttributes, copyItems: true) as? [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes] else { return nil }

    let interItemSpacing = minimumInteritemSpacing

    switch scrollDirection {
    case .horizontal:
        let leftPadding: CGFloat = self.sectionInset.left
        var leftMargin: CGFloat = leftPadding // Modified to determine origin.x for each item
        var maxY: CGFloat = -1.0 // Modified to determine origin.y for each item
        var rowSizes: [[CGFloat]] = [] // Tracks the starting and ending x-values for the first and last item in the row
        var currentRow: Int = 0 // Tracks the current row
        attributes.forEach { layoutAttribute in
            // Each layoutAttribute represents its own item
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {

                // This layoutAttribute represents the left-most item in the row
                leftMargin = leftPadding

                currentRow += rowSizes.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
                // Register its origin.x in rowSizes for use later
                rowSizes.append([leftMargin, 0])
            }
            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin
            leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + interItemSpacing
            maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)
            // Add right-most x value for last item in the row
            rowSizes[currentRow][1] = leftMargin - interItemSpacing
        }
        // At this point, all cells are left aligned
        // Reset tracking values and add extra left padding to center align entire row
        leftMargin = leftPadding
        maxY = -1.0
        currentRow = 0
        attributes.forEach { (layoutAttribute) in
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y >= maxY {

                // This layoutAttribute represents the left-most item in the row
                leftMargin = leftPadding

                // Need to bump it up by an appended margin
                let rowWidth = rowSizes[currentRow][1] - rowSizes[currentRow][0] // last.x - first.x
                let appendedMargin = (collectionView.frame.width - leftPadding  - rowWidth - leftPadding) / 2
                leftMargin += appendedMargin

                currentRow += 1
            }

            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x = leftMargin

            leftMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.width + interItemSpacing
            maxY = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxY, maxY)
        }

    case .vertical:
        let topPadding: CGFloat = self.sectionInset.top
        var topMargin: CGFloat = topPadding
        var maxX: CGFloat = -1.0 // Modified to determine origine.x for each item
        var colSizes: [[CGFloat]] = [] // Tracks the starting and ending y-values for the first and last item in the column
        var currentCol: Int = 0
        attributes.forEach { (layoutAttribute) in
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x >= maxX {
                topMargin = topPadding

                currentCol += colSizes.isEmpty ? 0 : 1
                colSizes.append([topMargin, 0])
            }

            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y = topMargin
            topMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.height + interItemSpacing
            maxX = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxX, maxX)
            colSizes[currentCol][1] = topMargin - interItemSpacing
        }
        topMargin = topPadding
        maxX = -1.0
        currentCol = 0
        attributes.forEach { (layoutAttribute) in
            if layoutAttribute.frame.origin.x >= maxX {

                topMargin = topPadding

                let colWidth = colSizes[currentCol][1] - colSizes[currentCol][0]
                let appendedMargin = (collectionView.frame.height - topPadding - colWidth - topPadding) / 2
                topMargin += appendedMargin

                currentCol += 1
            }

            layoutAttribute.frame.origin.y = topMargin

            topMargin += layoutAttribute.frame.height + interItemSpacing
            maxX = max(layoutAttribute.frame.maxX, maxX)
        }
    }

    return attributes
}
```